# How to fix this NullPointerException JavaFX8

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm programming an JavaFX application for my university scholarship, but in some part of my application has an exception exploding, this exception only explode when I try to change the Scene.

Here are the problematic code

```
public void nextButtonAction() throws Exception {
  FXMLLoader secondScreen = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/SecondScreen.fxml"));
  Parent root = secondScreen.load();

  SecondScreenController secondScreenController = secondScreen.getController();
  secondScreenController.setPorts(this.sensorPort, this.gpsPort);

  Stage stage = (Stage) this.nextButton.getScene().getWindow();
  stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 320, 480));
  stage.show();
}
```

and here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.MenuBarSkin.lambda$new$383(MenuBarSkin.java:304)
at javafx.event.WeakEventHandler.handle(WeakEventHandler.java:79)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$WeakEventFilterRecord.handleCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:312)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:223)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:180)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The exception doesn't seem to be thrown by the code you posted. It looks like it is something to do with a menu bar defined - perhaps - in the FXML file you are loading. Please create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it. There's no real way to diagnose the problem without that.